# Get Teams Call state

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, user-presence

When I start a call in Teams my user status is set to "*busy-inacall*" and as I have set "busy-on-busy" in the Teams admin policies, I am not available for a call anymore.
When I'm in a call and a planned meeting in Outlook starts the user status is set to "*busy-inAmeeting*" and I'm still not available for a call anymore.
When I'm not in a call and a planned meeting in Outlook starts, I am set to "*busy-inAmeeting*" as well but I'm available for a call.

So the user status/presence does not display the availability for a call.
How can I get (via MS Graph) if is user is available for a call?

Comment: We have [Get presence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Graph API which gives a user's presence information. Which include information about a user's presence, including their availability and user activity. Could you please confirm if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, no. As I described the "get presence" just returns "busy-inameeting". There is no distinction between available for a call or not

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other API available for your exact requirement.